# How come my HTML Include wont work?

Tags: html, include

I am making a site right now and I want to include the sidebar in every page. I have looked everywhere and everyone says to use the following code:

```
<!--#include virtual="insertthisfile.html" -->
```

I have done this but to no avail. I am using dreamweaver for easier uploading and managing of my files, and it shows up in dreamweaver. I would just use PHP but I dont want all of my pages to be PHP for just one code that can work in HTML..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make sure the (including) file has a `.shtml` extension
- Make sure server-side includes are enabled in the web server

Answer (score 6):

That isn't an "HTML" feature. It's [Server-Side Includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html). You need to make sure you have SSI active on your server and that it's set to apply to the file.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for including?

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html) has a lot of info on Server and Client side includes. It shows a couple of alternatives to the #include also.

Start by trying to rename the *.html* file to *.shtml*. Also, make sure server side includes are enabled on your server.

Comment: Turns out server side includes are already active, once I changed the extension to .shtml it worked. Thanks.