# data not shown using include tag in html5

Tags: html, include

i m using html5 and want to create page like master page in asp, i m craete page index.html and mainpage.html and want to call on click of link that exist in index page include mainpage.html. i use code on index page :

```
<!--#include virtual="mainpage.html" -->
```

but when we run index page it will show blank page

Can anyone please help me

Comment: may be this duplicate can help you [how come my html include wont work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817922/how-come-my-html-include-wont-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the include tag file extension is always .shtml and Check server-side include tags are enabled in the web server.

Answer (score 1):

1. That's a comment tag. Nothing you put in there is going to do anything.
2. There's no such thing as an html5 include tag.

Comment: But if you use [Server Side Includes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525185.aspx), it will work (for static pages).

Answer (score 0):

> “There's no such thing as an html5 include tag” @Fibericon

But you are trying to use [ssi include command](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341/SSI-The-Include-Command.htm)

Use this command and you will be satisfied, but you need a server environment (e.g. apache)